# SOLR stemming and stopwords

Tags: solr, stemming, stop-words

In SOLR 3.5 text field type the StopFilterFactory is listed before the PorterStemFilterFactory.

does this mean that if I wanted to stop for example "game" and "games" I would have to add both to stopwords?

if so would moving the StopFilterFactory after the PorterStemFilterFactory, and adding just "game" to stopwords cause occurrences of both "game" and "games" to be stripped?

I guess the true question is what is the best way to do this, and do I need to add all variations of the word to stopwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PorterStemFilterFactory` provides agressive stemming and having is before stop word filter may not cause proper stop word removal as the root may be different then the one you are trying to stop.
You can add handling for plurals only you can use `solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory` before the stop word filter.
This would handle the plurals and the stop words would then need to handle just the singular version.
You can then add the PorterStemFilterFactory filter to handle the proper stemming.

Comment: Thanks - that answer has opened my eyes quite a bit as to how solr can be used!

Comment: *before* meaning how you order these filters for a particular field?